# Move a video or audio element to another place without disconnecting stream (Cut & Paste)

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I am a frontend developer in a startup that is working on a video conference platofrm and we want to move the participant component to a sidebar when they mute their camera and place it back when they unmute without disconnecting the stream.

Something like what [whereby](https://whereby.com/) is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving elements in the DOM may cause them to be paused. Calling play() after moving them should suffice. Alternatively, use a separate  element that you don't move and that is not visible.

Comment: Thanks for answering, you mean I should clone the current video stream and asign it to the hidden element?

Comment: you don't need to clone, you can assign the same mediastream to multiple elements.